# Best way to automize a layout

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing, layout

I am new to classes and I would like to make a class that automatizes the complete layout of the document. This includes :

- setting a given pdf file as background,
- there is a different background in title page than in the rest of the document,
- the document ID, and document name should be in title page and in header of following pages.

I managed to put the background, no problem with that. But after hours of searching I couldn't find a way to automatize the pre-filling of recurrent text such as the ID and the subject.

Here a minimalist working example of my `my_class.cls` file :

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{my_class}[2023/03/10 A document class for my compagny documents]
\LoadClass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\RequirePackage{palatino}
\RequirePackage{mathpazo}

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[french]{babel}

\RequirePackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.4cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

% The background
\RequirePackage[pages=1]{background}
\backgroundsetup{scale = 1.01, angle = 0, opacity = 1,
  contents = {
            \ifnum\thepage = 1 \includegraphics[width = \paperwidth, height = \paperheight, keepaspectratio]{bg_title.pdf}
            \else \includegraphics[width = \paperwidth, height = \paperheight, keepaspectratio]{bg_all.pdf}
            \fi}}
            
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfootoffset[R]{-0.35cm}
\fancyfoot[R]{\color{white}\vspace{-0.05cm}\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyheadoffset[R]{-0.30cm}
\fancyhead[R]{document_name \hspace{0.5cm}\textbf{\color{white}document_ID}}

% Title page
\AtBeginDocument{
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
       \vspace*{0.15\textheight}
       \textbf{\huge document_ID -- client}
       
       \vspace{0.8cm}
       \textbf{\huge project_name}   
       
       \vspace{0.8cm}
       \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{title_page_logo}
       \vspace{0.8cm}
       
       \textbf{\huge document_name}
       \vfill
       
       This document is confidential
       
       \vspace{0.8cm}
       
       Date de la dernière mise à jour du document : \today \\
       Rédacteur(s) du document : redactor
            
\end{center}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
}
```

And in my `tex` file,

```
\documentclass{my_class}


\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

So in my document, the basic laout is already there (background, headers, etc.), however, you can see in the `cls` file that there is some informations that depends on the document :

- `document_ID` (headers and title page)
- `document_name` (headers and title page)
- `client` (title page)
- `project_name` (title page)
- `title_page_logo` (title page)
- `redactor` (title page)

(for us it's important to automatize this kind of stuff => all the documents will have the exact same layout, and if you don't enter all informations, there is an error and the document can't be compiled).

I search something like when you call `\author{...}`, and calling `\document_ID{ID 1235}`
for instance, but it's not via classes that it works.

Is there a way to do something like that ? Or at least in the tex file just calling the class using : `\documentclass[document_ID=ID 1235,...]{my_class}` or something like that ?

I read a lot about `\DeclareOptions`, but I am not sure it is suited for "string input" like here ! (or I just did not understood how it works).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: basically everything is possible, but you will have to describe better how you want to input the data.  Unrelated: don't do typesetting in the \AtBeginDocument hook. Not everything is already correctly setup there. Use the `begindocument/end`, see `texdoc lthooks` for more info. I wouldn't use the background package, that is based on tikz and imho to overloaded for a simple picture. Use the eso-pic package or the shipout/background hook.

Comment: I have observed that "I want to create a class" or "I want to create a sty file" indicates far more ambition than common sense.  You can generallly achieve the same effect with `\input`.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. Sorry if the formulation felt ambitious to you. It's just that by googling if step on more and more post "how to use classes", then I thought it would be the solution.

ALso sorry for the poor quality, I literally my first attempt doing a class. I will take a look at the `input` function ! :)

Comment: @JohnKormylo, your solution did the job, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me elaborate a bit on John Kormylo's comment. The following should do what you expect and does not bloat your main document. You will just have to define some values (document ID, document name, ...) at the beginning of your main file and import the `.tex` file containing the generic stuff. No need for fancy classes or similar stuff.
[image: Result]

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Fill in these information. Just do it!
\newcommand{\myDocID}{ID~0123456789}
\newcommand{\myDocName}{Important Document}
\newcommand{\myClient}{Claire Client}
\newcommand{\myProjName}{Important Project}
\newcommand{\myTitleLogo}{example-image-duck}
\newcommand{\myEditor}{Ph.\,D.~Eddy Editor}

% Additional packages.
\usepackage{lipsum} % Just to have some blindtext.

% Input generic setup stuff.
\input{genericSetup.tex}

% Start of document.
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

`genericSetup.tex`

```
% Necessary packages. If you need to load any package with certain options, e.g. `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`, make sure you have this line *before* `\input`ting this code.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

% Apply `fancyhdr` stuff.
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfootoffset[R]{-0.35cm}
\fancyfoot[R]{\color{white}\vspace{-0.05cm}\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyheadoffset[R]{-0.30cm}
\fancyhead[R]{\myDocName \hspace{0.5cm}\textbf{\color{white}\myDocID{}}}

% Define behavior at start of the document.
\AtBeginDocument{
    % Create titlepage.
    \begin{titlepage}
        \centering
        \ClearShipoutPicture
        \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}% replace with a fixed titlepage background image
        \vspace*{0.15\textheight}
           \textbf{\huge \myDocID{} -- \myClient}
           
           \vspace{0.8cm}
           \textbf{\huge \myProjName}
           
           \vspace{0.8cm}
           \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{\myTitleLogo}
           \vspace{0.8cm}
           
           \textbf{\huge \myDocName}
           \vfill
           
           This document is confidential.
           
           \vspace{0.8cm}
           
           Date de la dernière mise à jour du document : \today \\
           Rédacteur(s) du document: \myEditor
    \end{titlepage}
    
    % Define background for non-titlepage pages *after* printing the titlepage.
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}}% replace with a fixed titlepage background image
}
```